# Emacs c-mode can't recognize utf-8?

Tags: emacs, encoding, cc-mode

I need to read one C++ head file which has some Chinese and was encoded using utf-8.

Emacs should recognize this encoding, but it turns out:

[image]

Then, I changed it to text-mode, it works:

[image]

I also tested for python-mode, lisp-mode, etc, all works except c-mode, c++-mode, java-mode, seems there are something wrong with cc-mode, or the cc-vars?

Please help me if you know how to fix this weird problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks more like a missing font (rather than encoding) issue; i.e., your system lacks a properly configured Chinese italic font.

Comment: I think its definitely some thing to do with emacs since the same characters are fine in the text-mode.

Comment: Wrong - it c-mode the font is in italics, in text mode it's not. The font used is missing an italics version I guess.

Comment: @Bozhidar Yes, seems it's the reason, do you guys know how to disable comment italic in cc-mode?

Comment: OK, I get it `(make-face-unitalic 'font-lock-comment-face)`, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is arguably a bug in Emacs: it should fallback to some other font (non-italics, if needed) rather than display blank squares.  We have fixed a few such problems ober the years, so try the latest Emacs-24 pretest to see if the bug is already fixed there, and otherwise `M-x report-emacs-bug`